# creating a jquery plugin: this.html is not a function

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm following [this documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and use it to download and apply data to the DOM. However, I don't seem to be able to apply it as I'm getting:

> this.html is not a function: this.html(ajax_load);

Code:

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.tasks = function() {

    // there's no need to do $(this) because
    // "this" is already a jquery object

    // $(this) would be the same as $($('#element'));

    $.ajax({
        url: "include/tasks_handler.php?action=gettasks&list=default",
        beforeSend: function() {
            this.html(ajax_load);
        },
        success: function(html){
            this.html(html);
        }
    });

  };
})( jQuery );


$("#taskList").tasks();
```

I've also tried $(this), which stops it from breaking, but it's not injecting the content to the selector.

Ideas?

Comment: Use `$(this)` to make it a jQuery object that has the `.html` method. Post what happens *then* as the problem (because that's the actual problem :)

Comment: @FLX: What are you trying to refer to with `this`?

Comment: also, `this` would not be available to the scope of the callback to beforeSend .. you'd have to do `var somevar = this;` to make it visible inside the callback -- funny `this` scoping rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` within the ajax options refers to the *options object* and not the context of the plugin. A workaround is:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
    url: "include/tasks_handler.php?action=gettasks&list=default",
    beforeSend: function() {
        that.html(ajax_load);
    },
    success: function(html){
        that.html(html);
    }
});
```

This quick example demonstrates what's happening:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        alert("bar");
    },
    bar: function() {
        alert(this.foo);
    }
};

obj.bar(); // function() { alert("bar"); }
```

This example better demonstrates what's happening:

```
var options = {
    success: function(html) {
        this.html(html);
    },
    html: function(html) {
        alert("This is not the .html() you are looking for, move along." + html);     
    } 
}

options.success("some html");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GTScL/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to fix you self executing function first
then create a variable for html before trying to pass it into another function

```
(function ($) {

      $.fn.tasks = function () {

            var ele = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                    url: "include/tasks_handler.php?action=gettasks&list=default",
                    beforeSend: function() {
                           ele.html(ajax_load);
                    },
                    success: function(html){
                           ele.html(html);
                    }
            });
      };

}( jQuery )); // Bracket goes after
```